# TS2322: Type '(data: TicketFullDTO) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to create a edit form to edit data from database by id. I tries this:

```
    import React, {FormEvent, useEffect, useState} from "react";
    import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import {
      TicketFullDTO,
      TicketStatusTypesDTO,
    } from "../../service/support/types";
    import {
      getTicket,
      getTicketStatusTypes,
      updateTicket,
    } from "../../service/support";
    import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
    import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
    import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
    import { FormControl } from "@mui/material";
    import { Moment } from "moment";
    import { RouteParams } from "../../service/utils";
       
    export default function TicketProfile(props: any) {
      const classes = useStyles();
      let history = useHistory();
      let requestParams = useParams<RouteParams>();

      const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("");
      const [submitDate, setSubmitDate] = useState<Moment | null>(null);
    
      // This won't be run unless all the input validations are met.
      const onSubmit = async (data: TicketFullDTO) => {
        console.log(data);

        updateTicket(requestParams.id, data)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            console.log(data.title);
            history.replace("/support");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      };
    
      const [ticketCategoriesList, setTicketCategoriesList] = useState<
        TicketCategoryTypesDTO[]
      >([]);
      const [ticket, setTicket] = useState<TicketFullDTO>();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getSingleTicket();
      }, []);
    
      const getSingleTicket = async () => {
        getTicket(requestParams.id)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            setTicket(data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };
    
      const [ticketStatusList, setTicketStatusList] = useState<
        TicketStatusTypesDTO[]
      >([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        ticketStatusData();
      }, []);
    
      const ticketStatusData = async () => {
        getTicketStatusTypes()
          .then((resp) => {
            setTicketStatusList(resp.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };
    
      return (
        <Container>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>

                          .........

                          <TextField
                            value={ticket?.title}
                            id="title"                                             
                            onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                              setTicket({ ...ticket, title: value });
                            }}
                          />

                          .........

                          <FormControl>
                            <TextField
                              label="Submit Date"
                              id="submit-date"
                              type="date"
                              defaultValue={ticket?.submitDate}                             
                              //@ts-ignore
                              onInput={(e) => setSubmitDate(e.target.value)}
                            />
                          </FormControl>
                       
                          ..........

                            <Select
                              labelId="status-label"
                              id="status-helper"
                              value={ticket?.status}
                              onChange={(e) => setStatus(e.target.value)}
                              required
                            >
                              {ticketStatusList.map((element) => (
                                <MenuItem value={element.code}>
                                  {element.name}
                                </MenuItem>
                              ))}
                            </Select>
                          </FormControl>

                         ...........
                      
                          <Button
                            type="submit"
                          >
                            Update Ticket
                          </Button>                       
    
        </Container>
      );
    }


.....


export async function updateTicket(
    id: string,
    data: TicketFullDTO
): Promise<AxiosResponse<TicketFullDTO>> {
  return await axios.post<TicketFullDTO>(
      `${baseUrl}/management/support/tickets/ticket/${id}`,
      {
        data,
      }
  );
}

export interface TicketFullDTO {
    id?: number,
    title?: string,
    status?: string,
    submitDate?: Moment | null
}
```

I at this line: `<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>` I get this error:

```
TS2322: Type '(data: TicketFullDTO) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>'.   Types of parameters 'data' and 'event' are incompatible.     Type 'FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>' has no properties in common with type 'TicketFullDTO'.  index.d.ts(1390, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onSubmit' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>'
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: the `onSubmit` eventhandler of a form  (which you assign with `<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>` has to be a `FormEventHandler` (ie among other things it has to accept an `Event` as first parameter). The `onSubmit` function you try to register as event handler accepts a `TicketFullDTO` as first parameter.  How to fix? Define a [proper eventhandler](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you want to use is the `ticket` state variable as your `data` since all your fields are updating that state variable, which would be done as follow:

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
  updateTicket(requestParams.id, ticket)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(data.title);
      history.replace("/support");
    })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

The reason why your type validation is failing is because the `onSubmit` event handler gets the event as a parameter, so if you do want to make use of the parameter, you would do the following (where `e` would be the event object):

```
const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
...
```